# merge dataframe but do not sort by merge key

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to merge `df1` and `df2` to `df3` and keep order. my demo code add `sort=False` but it not work as expected.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [
    ['4A', 1],
    ['3B', 2],
    ['2C', 3],
    ['1D', 4],
    ]
data2 = [
    ['2C', 9],
    ['4A', 3],
    ['6F', 2],
    ['5G', 1],
    ]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['name', 'value'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['name', 'value'])

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='name', sort=False)
df3 = df3.rename({'value_x': 'v1', 'value_y': 'y2'}, axis=1)
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
  name  value
0   4A      1
1   3B      2
2   2C      3
3   1D      4
  name  value
0   2C      9
1   4A      3
2   6F      2
3   5G      1
  name   v1   y2
0   1D  4.0  NaN
1   2C  3.0  9.0
2   3B  2.0  NaN
3   4A  1.0  3.0
4   5G  NaN  1.0
5   6F  NaN  2.0
```

Expected output:

```
  name   v1   y2
0   4A  1.0  3.0
1   3B  2.0  NaN
2   2C  3.0  9.0
3   1D  4.0  NaN
4   6F  NaN  2.0
5   5G  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Weird, I get the expected (unsorted) output on Pandas 2.0.3, but not Pandas 2.2.1. The documentation doesn't seem to have changed.

Comment: Note that `sort=False` is the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming sorted range indexes, [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) before [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html), then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df3 = (pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(),
                how='outer', on='name', sort=False)
         .sort_values(by=['index_x', 'index_y'],
                      ignore_index=True)
         .drop(columns=['index_x', 'index_y'])
         .rename({'value_x': 'v1','value_y':'y2'}, axis=1)
      )
```

For a more generic case:

```
df3 = (pd.merge(df1.assign(index=np.arange(len(df1))),
                df2.assign(index=np.arange(len(df2))),
                how='outer', on='name', sort=False)
         .sort_values(by=['index_x', 'index_y'],
                      ignore_index=True)
         .drop(columns=['index_x', 'index_y'])
         .rename({'value_x': 'v1','value_y':'y2'}, axis=1)
      )
```

Alternatively, use the union of `df1['name']`/`df2['name']` to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
idx = pd.concat([df1['name'], df2['name']]).drop_duplicates()

df3 = (pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='name', sort=False)
         .set_index('name').reindex(idx).reset_index()
         .rename({'value_x': 'v1','value_y':'y2'}, axis=1)
      )
```

Output:

```
  name   v1   y2
0   4A  1.0  3.0
1   3B  2.0  NaN
2   2C  3.0  9.0
3   1D  4.0  NaN
4   6F  NaN  2.0
5   5G  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: Great answer, but still confusing why sort=False no effect?

Comment: `merge=False` doesn't mean that the original order is maintained, it means that the key won't explicitly be sorted. Then the order depends on the type of `merge`. Try with an inner `merge` to see the difference: `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='name', sort=False)`